# .htaccess file, IE not working Firefox, Safari & Chrome working

Tags: internet-explorer, .htaccess

I've built a site in Interspire Web Publisher and it was working fine, seems to work in Firefox, Safari and Chrome but when I fired up Internet Explorer 7 & 8 only the home page works, all links to other pages show up nothing.

Do you think it could have something to do with the .htaccess file? But why would it work at one point then not another? I did a test new site (its database driven) with 3 small pages and it worked fine on Internet Explorer....very weird!

my website: http://www.artandepilepsy.com

Comment: I received an error on Firefox, then refreshed the page and got the proper index.  I think you have something else going on, and I don't think it's related to .htaccess.

Comment: Something is definitely not right.  Could you post your .htaccess file here?

Comment: for me it's not working the link you pasted :-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your browser (Internet Explorer) is caching the page before you set up the .htaccess file?  Try deleting your Internet caches in all your browsers, then restart your browser.  If it still works, then you've got a weird issue, if not, then it's your .htaccess file.

Comment: Accessing the site just now, getting a php error.  Looks like something else is broken too...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot guys for taking the time to reply...what the hell could be happening if Safari, Firefox and Chrome are all fine (I guess they are all built on the same Webkit (corrected). What would IE be doing differently? It seemed fine in an earlier version of Interspire but I don't want to go back to that as it doesnt have feedback forms!

I've cleared the cache within Interspire (the CMS system I am using) and in Internet Explorer but still no joy. I've even setup a new install here: http://www.artandepilepsy.com/version2/ (ignore the big heading text) but I get the same problem.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
# Options:
# -MultiViews: Turns off multiviews so it doesn't interfer with our rewrite rules
# -Indexes: Stop directory listings
# +FollowSymlinks: Let out rewrite rules work

Options -MultiViews -Indexes +FollowSymlinks

# Disable any sending of a default character set
AddDefaultCharset OFF

# Disable etags -- less headers

RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /

<IfModule mod_security.c>
    # Turn off mod_security filtering.  
    SecFilterEngine Off

    # The below probably isn't needed, but better safe than sorry.
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript application/javascript text/css text/ html text/xml
</IfModule>


# PHP is in CGI Mode, so we need a different mod_rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: Off-topic, but Safari and Chrome both use WebKit, not Gecko.